# Foreign Key Referencing multiple lines

Tags: mysql

this is my very first post in StackOverflow and english is not my best so... *HappyFace* x)

So i'm having a bit of an issue in my conception of a project, i'm trying to make a DB for my university that store exam and such, but i'm facing a problem i didnt think of in my first analyse of the system, some exams are made for multiples classes and in my conception an exam can only reference a single classe.

I use a table called Sujet that containt multiple data, one of them is a foreign key called Filiere and it is referencing the id of another table Filiere(id), i want the foreign key to reference **multiple lines** of the Filiere table, is it possible? if no is there a work-around?

Comment: You need to define a "many-to-many" relationship, making use of 3 tables -- one listing the course, one listing the exams, and a third which has foreign keys pointing to *both* a course and an exam.  There are many examples on this site -- I will try to search for one...

Comment: Here is a concise example on the DBA site: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29675/many-to-many-relationships  It describes students and courses, similar to your exams and courses.  Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: Woooow, man thanks!! i didn't even know about something like that. 

I feel stupid for not thinking about it x) Thanks again!!